# twitter4Jで複数画像を投稿したいのですが、一度ファイルを取得しているにもかかわらずファイルがないと言われますどのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？

Tags: android, eclipse, 画像, twitter4j

はじめまして。
今、twitter4jを使用してTwitterクライアントアプリを作成しています。
複数画像をメッセージと同時に投稿したいのですが、一度ファイルを取得しているにも関わらず
ファイルが存在しないことになってしまいます。
何がいけないのでしょうか？ご教示願います。

```
public class TweetActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mInputText;
private Twitter mTwitter;
private Button mGazou;
private ImageView imageView,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4;
private Boolean gazou=false;
UploadedMedia media1=null;
UploadedMedia media2=null;
UploadedMedia media3=null;
UploadedMedia media4=null;
int k =0;
Uri[] multi_uri=null;
Uri uri = null;
InputStream in;
long[]mediaIds = null;
long media_id =0;

private static final int RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE = 1001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_tweet);

    mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(this);
    //Twitter文字入力
    mInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    //Twitter画像選択（ギャラリーから）
    mGazou = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mGazou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.action_tweet).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //tweet();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,final Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode != RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //mTwitterはOAuth認可済みであるとする
                String message = "hello";
                ClipData clipData = resultData.getClipData();
                long[] mediaIds = new long[clipData.getItemCount()];
                for (int i = 0, length = clipData.getItemCount(); i < length; i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    mediaIds[i] = (mTwitter.uploadMedia(String.format("[filename_%d]", i + 1), getContentResolver().openInputStream(item.getUri())).getMediaId());
                }

                StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate(message);
                update.setMediaIds(mediaIds);
                mTwitter.updateStatus(update);

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_tweet_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_not:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

ログキャットは以下のように出力されます。

```
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099): Process: android.example.shutwitter, PID: 3099
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity.showToast(TweetActivity.java:238)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity.access$1(TweetActivity.java:237)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity$3.doInBackground(TweetActivity.java:99)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity$3.doInBackground(TweetActivity.java:1)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-26 05:10:17.700: E/AndroidRuntime(3099):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ギャラリーから取得したURIを`File`に渡していますが、`File`のAPIが扱える`Path`とはファイルパス（`file:`スキーマのもの）であって、Androidの`Content Provider`が返すコンテンツURI（`content:`スキーマのもの）ではないのが原因です。

`Content Provider`が返却したコンテンツURIから実際のファイルを取得するには、`Content Resolver`を利用する必要があります。公式ドキュメントの[コンテンツ プロバイダの作成](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)などを参考にしてみてください。`ImageView`に画像が表示されるのは、Glideのフレームワークが内部で`ContentResolver`を用いているためです。

ここでは、[ストレージ アクセス フレームワーク](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)を用いて画像を取得していますが、SAFから取得したコンテンツURIを実際のファイルパスに変換するよりも、`InputStream`を引数に取れる`uploadMedia(java.lang.String fileName, java.io.InputStream media)`を利用した方が簡単かと思います。

`getContentResolver().openInputStream(resultData.getData())`でストリームを取得できます。

---

問題を単純化して、Twitter4Jを用いて複数枚の画像を同時にアップロードするという処理を書く場合は以下のような感じになります。

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,final Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode != RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //mTwitterはOAuth認可済みであるとする
                String message = "hello";
                ClipData clipData = resultData.getClipData();
                long[] mediaIds = new long[clipData.getItemCount()];
                for (int i = 0, length = clipData.getItemCount(); i < length; i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    mediaIds[i] = (mTwitter.uploadMedia(String.format("[filename_%d]", i + 1), getContentResolver().openInputStream(item.getUri())).getMediaId());
                }

                StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate(message);
                update.setMediaIds(mediaIds);
                mTwitter.updateStatus(update);

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
 }
```

Comment: 回答有難うございます。
返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません。回答が来てからずっとプログラムを組んでました。
八方塞がりでContent Providerが必要と分かっただけで大きな収穫でした。
数時間かけてプログラムを組んでましたが、タイムラインが取得しなくなり、ログキャットにもエラーが出て強制終了するようになりました。
uploadMedia(java.lang.String fileName, java.io.InputStream media)も試してみましたが、uploadMediaの部分にエラーが出てfileNameだけにしろと言われました。

Comment: 利用されているTwitter4Jのバージョンはいくつでしょうか？現在のTwitter4Jの安定バージョンは4.0.4ですが、InputStreamを引数に取るメソッドが追加されているのが4.0.3からになります。タイムラインが取得できなくなったのは、API limitに引っかかったからではないかと推察します。

Comment: 再度有難うございます。
Twitter4jのバージョンは4.0.4を使用しております。
最新版の安定している分を使っているのですが、ContentResolverの使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？

Comment: @RJ_mic ストレージアクセスフレームワークから取得したパスを、実際の物理パスに変換するのは極めて困難（というより自分は確実な手段を知らないです、不可能だと断じる根拠もないので困難という書き方をしていますが）です。いったん`Bitmap`に変換してテンポラリファイルを作成するか、上のコード例のように、`uploadMedia()`に`InputStream`を渡すのが楽だと思います（実際に試してみたところ複数枚画像をアップロードできました）。

Comment: 重ね重ね本当に有難うございます。Genymotionで複数選択の際画像が投稿できたことを確認できました。
単体は自分で頑張ってみます。