# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()の原因は？

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

お世話になっております。
[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24293/twitter4j%E3%81%A7%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C-%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B)の質問では回答有難うございました。
無事、複数枚画像の投稿にすることが成功しました。
今回はその続きで、投稿はできているものの、`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`がログキャトに出力されておりアプリが強制終了します。
ツイート自体は成功しているのですが、アプリが落ちてしまい困り果てました。
何かいい解決策はないでしょうか？ご教示願います。

```
public class TweetActivity extends Activity {

private EditText mInputText;
private Twitter mTwitter;
private Button mGazou;
private ImageView imageView,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4;
private Boolean gazou=false;
UploadedMedia media1=null;
UploadedMedia media2=null;
UploadedMedia media3=null;
UploadedMedia media4=null;
int k =0;
Uri[] multi_uri=null;
Uri uri = null;
InputStream in;
long[]mediaIds = null;
long media_id =0;

private static final int RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE = 1001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_tweet);

    mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(this);
    //Twitter文字入力
    mInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    //Twitter画像選択（ギャラリーから）
    mGazou = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mGazou.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.action_tweet).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //tweet();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,final Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode != RESULT_PICK_IMAGEFILE || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                //mTwitterはOAuth認可済みであるとする
                String message = "画像テストじゃおりゃぁぁぁぁぁぁぁぁ！！！！！！！！";
                ClipData clipData = resultData.getClipData();


                if(clipData!=null){
                    mediaIds = new long[clipData.getItemCount()];
                    for (int i = 0, length = clipData.getItemCount(); i < length; i++) {
                         ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                         mediaIds[i] = (mTwitter.uploadMedia(String.format("[filename_%d]", i + 1), getContentResolver().openInputStream(item.getUri())).getMediaId());
                    }

                }else{
                       Log.i("flag", "１枚通過");
                            uri = resultData.getData();
                            Log.i("flag", uri.toString());
                            mediaIds = new long[1];
                            mediaIds[0] =(mTwitter.uploadMedia(String.format("[filename_%d]",1), getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)).getMediaId());
                            Log.i("flag", String.valueOf(mediaIds[0]));
                }
                         StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate(message);
                         update.setMediaIds(mediaIds);
                         mTwitter.updateStatus(update);
                         showToast("投稿できました！");




            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_tweet_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_not:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}





/* private void tweet() {
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {

                    //画像アップロード
                    if(gazou==true){

                        if(k>0){
                            mediaIds = new long[k];
                        }else if(k==0){
                            mediaIds=new long[1];
                        }

                        StatusUpdate update = new StatusUpdate(params[0]);
                        switch(k){
                            case 0:
                                try {
                                    media1 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,uri)));
                                    mediaIds[0]=media1.getMediaId();


                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                try {
                                    media1 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[0])));
                                    media2 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[1])));
                                    mediaIds[0]=media1.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[1]=media2.getMediaId();
                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                try {
                                    media1 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[0])));
                                    media2 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[1])));
                                    media3 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[2])));
                                    mediaIds[0]=media1.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[1]=media2.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[2]=media3.getMediaId();
                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;
                            case 4:

                                try {
                                    media1 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[0])));
                                    media2 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[1])));
                                    media3 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[2])));
                                    media4 = mTwitter.uploadMedia(new File(getPath(TweetActivity.this,multi_uri[3])));
                                    mediaIds[0]=media1.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[1]=media2.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[2]=media3.getMediaId();
                                    mediaIds[3]=media4.getMediaId();
                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                    // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        Log.i("ImageCount", "画像選択枚数："+String.valueOf(k));
                        Log.i("ImageTAG", mediaIds.toString());
                        update.setMediaIds(mediaIds);
                        mTwitter.updateStatus(update);
                    }else{
                        mTwitter.updateStatus(params[0]);
                    }

                    return true;
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (result) {
                    showToast("ツイートが完了しました！");
                    showToast("×ボタンを押して元の画面に戻ってね");
                    mInputText.setText("");

                } else {
                    showToast("ツイートに失敗しました。。。");
                }
            }
        };
        task.execute(mInputText.getText().toString());
    }*/

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

## ログキャット

```
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): Process: android.example.shutwitter, PID: 4995
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:250)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity.showToast(TweetActivity.java:253)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity.access$1(TweetActivity.java:252)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity$3.doInBackground(TweetActivity.java:111)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.example.shutwitter.TweetActivity$3.doInBackground(TweetActivity.java:1)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-26 07:44:57.408: E/AndroidRuntime(4995):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Toast`を含めたUIの処理は、UIスレッド（メインスレッドとも呼ばれます）で行われています。

対して、[`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)は非同期処理を行うクラスのため、別のスレッドにて動作しています。このエラーは`doInBackground()`内から、直接`Toast`の表示（＝UIスレッドへの操作）はできないということを意味しています。

より厳密に説明するならば、バックグラウンドスレッドからUIスレッドへ、`Handler`クラスを用いてスレッド間の通信を行おうとしているのですが、バックグラウンドスレッドのイベントループが回っていない（[`Looper#prepare()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/os/Looper.html)がコールされていない）ので、メッセージが送れないため、この例外が発生します。

解決策としては、`AsyncTask`にはUIスレッドへ処理の進捗や結果を表示するための、コールバックメソッドが用意されていますので、そちらを利用すると良いと思います。

例えば、ツイートが成功した、という情報が必要であれば、`AsyncTask`の型パラメータ（`<Void, Void, Void>`の部分）のうち、最後の型パラメータを`Boolean`にして、`doInBackground()`で結果の成否を返すようにします。

`doInBackground()`の返り値で`onPostExecute()`が呼び出されます。このコールバックメソッド内ではUIスレッドにアクセスできますので、成否に応じて`Toast`を表示することができます。

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
           // 省略
           mTwitter.updateStatus(update);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result) {
            showToast("投稿に成功しました");
        } else {
            showToast("投稿に失敗しました");
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: 重ね重ね本当に有難うございます。
おかげで無事完成しそうです。
トースト表示は別途わけないといけないのですね。
肝に銘じます。